# Inheritance regardless of input parameters

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, arguments, virtual-functions

I would like to create interface class and then inherit derived class from this.
Unfortunately there can be multiple types of derived classes - method with same name but different input parameters.

Here is class diagram of inherited classes
[image]

Is it possible to create InterfaceClass regardless of type (and count!) of input parameters?

What am I trying to achieve - to have multiple final children (SpecificWorker1..n) and each of them has to implement method of name "buildRequest" but on it's own, own set of input parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? Trying wouldn't take much longer than asking this question, and the compiler would answer you

Comment: yep..
When I declare "void buildRequest(std::list inputList)" it doesn't work because SpecificWorker1 is not overriding buildRequest() from InterfaceClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the reason why would you do this. But you can try this solution using variadic templates. Just trying to answer the question:

> Is it possible to create InterfaceClass regardless of type (and
>   count!) of input parameters?

```
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
class InterfaceClass
{
private:
    static void buildRequest() {};

public:
    virtual ~InterfaceClass() = default;
    virtual void buildRequest(Head h, Tail  ...t) = 0;
};

template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
class DefaultWorker : public InterfaceClass <Head, Tail...>
{
public:

    virtual void buildRequest(Head h, Tail  ...t) = 0;

};

class SpecificWorker1 : public DefaultWorker <std::list<int>, int>
{
public:

    void buildRequest(std::list<int> h, int g = 0) override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from SpecificWorker1. list size: " << h.size() << std::endl;
    }

};

class SpecificWorker2 : public DefaultWorker <int, float>
{
public:
    void buildRequest(int h, float f) override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from SpecificWorker2. " << h << " " << f << std::endl;
    }
};

class SpecificWorker3 : public DefaultWorker <int, float, std::string>
{
public:
    void buildRequest(int h, float f, std::string comment) override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from SpecificWorker3. int: " << h << " float:  " << f << " comment: " << comment << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SpecificWorker2 e;
    e.buildRequest(1, 1.1);

    std::list<int> list{ 1, 2, 3 };
    SpecificWorker1 c;
    c.buildRequest(list);

    SpecificWorker3 d;
    d.buildRequest(1, 1.1, "this is a comment");

    system("pause");

}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yep, variadic templates we found as best solution..
Eventhough it is not easy to look at it is working. :D

Probably we will do this that way.

Answer (score 2):

No, all your different overloads of buildrequest are separate methods and other than SpecificWorker3 all your classes are abstract as they don't implement the version without arguments.

What are you actually trying to achieve? How would you pass parameters to your overloads when your interface takes no parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that the way you want to. You could create an inheritance hierarchy of a struct where each child in the hierarchy wraps a different kind of parameter. However, this would completely defeat the purpose of having an interface and inheritance in the first place, as each implementation of your original interface would have to be able to handle all kinds of inputs.

To be honest, there is something rather fishy with you design and you should not have to do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Simply I would like to have as many different children (SpecificWorker 1..n) as possible, but each of them has to implement method of name "buildRequest", but in its own way.

Comment: @ZdenoPavlik How do you propose to call those `buildRequest` methods via the interface if they don't have the same signature?  Remember, the point of virtual functions is to call them without knowing which implementation you actually have.

Comment: If I would have know how to to do that easily I wouldn't be posting this question.

Comment: @ZdenoPavlik My point is that you can't.  You need to re-evaluate your design.  Perhaps pass the arguments to the SpecificWorker classes' constructors and store them?  Then all of them could implement `buildRequest` with the same no-argument signature.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Fortunately this is not designed yet, just being designed. And we are thinking of it.
Yep, passing arguments via constructor is possible.
Also is possible to create some DTO struct and just transfer all the data in it.
But we don't like neither of it.

I have expected that this approach will not work but before claiming final conclusion I wanted to found different opinions from people here...